# Memory leak in swift code

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, memory-leaks

I am new to swift. 
I am trying to write following code to find the hash. but seems this code is leaking.

```
func CalculateHash(InputStr: String) -> UInt64 {
    let PRIME = 12345678
    var hash: UInt64 = 0
    var iCnt: Int = 0
    let Strlen = countElements(InputStr)
    var UInt64EqOfChar: UInt64 = 0

    //    for (;iCnt < Strlen; ++iCnt) {
    for TmpChar in InputStr {
        //var CharName = InputStr[advance(InputStr.startIndex, iCnt)]
        for TmpData in String(TmpChar).unicodeScalars {
            UInt64EqOfChar = UInt64(TmpData.value)
        }
        hash += UInt64EqOfChar
        //        hash += (hash << 1)
        hash ^= (hash >> 6)
    }

    hash += (hash << 12)
    hash ^= (hash >> 23)
    hash += (hash << 34)
    hash = hash & UInt64(PRIME)
    return hash
}
```

[image: Leak from instruments attached here]

Comment: How do you know it's leaking?

Comment: Using instrument tool from xcode. It shows Error in next iterator of for loop.

Comment: You should use a consistent case convention. In Swift only types are capitalized while variable names begin with a lower case letter. Also I was unable to reproduce this issue (in Swift 3.2 and 4.0).

Comment: I updated your code for Swift 3.1.1. It compiles fine and there are no noticeable memory leaks under an Ubuntu system, even with large input strings. Update your Xcode and try this: https://hastebin.com/ijozagelah.bash. It seems to work without issue.

Comment: @Palle This code doesn't even compile under Swift 3/4. Seems to be 1.0 only. I did manage to update it however.